# How do you create your own moniker (URL Protocol) on Windows systems?

Tags: windows, winapi, moniker

How do you create your own custom moniker (or URL Protocol) on Windows systems?

Examples:

- http:
- mailto:
- service:

Comment: Windows? COM/OLE moniker (almost) predates the Internet.  http protocol handler is not com moniker.  [Example of a com moniker is "new:"](https://thrysoee.dk/InsideCOM+/ch11e.htm).  Will that work in e.g. Win11? [I am pretty sure it will](https://www.vbsedit.com/html/a0d71def-47b9-4797-837c-bef653d958aa.asp).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [Creating and Using URL Monikers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa741006(VS.85).aspx) , [About Asynchronous Pluggable Protocols](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767916(VS.85).aspx) and [Registering an Application to a URL Protocol](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914.aspx) from MSDN

Comment: Your Registering Link had the details I had in mind.  @Lasse's answer also contained the details.

Answer (score 3):

Here's some old Delphi code we used as a way to get shortcuts in a web application to start a windows program locally for the user.

```
procedure InstallIntoRegistry;
var
  Reg: TRegistry;
begin
  Reg := TRegistry.Create;
  try
    Reg.RootKey := HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT;
    if Reg.OpenKey('moniker', True) then
    begin
      Reg.WriteString('', 'URL:Name of moniker');
      Reg.WriteString('URL Protocol', '');
      Reg.WriteString('Source Filter', '{E436EBB6-524F-11CE-9F53-0020AF0BA770}');
      Reg.WriteInteger('EditFlags', 2);

      if Reg.OpenKey('shell\open\command', True) then
      begin
        Reg.WriteString('', '"' + ParamStr(0) + '" "%1"');
      end;
    end else begin
      MessageBox(0, 'You do not have the necessary access rights to complete this installation!' + Chr(13) +
        'Please make sure you are logged in with a user account with administrative rights!', 'Access denied', 0);
      Exit;
    end;
  finally
    FreeAndNil(Reg);
  end;

  MessageBox(0, 'Application WebStart has been installed successfully!', 'Installed', 0);
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

*Inside OLE* from Craig Brockschmidt probably has the best coverage on monikers. If you want to dig a little deeper into this topic, I'd recommend getting this book. It is also contained on the MSDN disk that came along with VS 6.0, in case you still have that.